# how to find the last modified file and then extract it

Tags: shell

Say I have 3 archrive file:

```
a.7z
b.7z
c.7z
```

What I want is to find the last modified archrive file and then extract it

> 1st: find the last modified
>
> 2nd: extract it

1st:

`ls -t | head -1`

**My question is how to approach 2nd by using "|" at the end of 1st command**

Comment: you can't answer inside your question, write it as an independent answer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like that:

```
7z e `ls -t | head -1`
```

Use `` to embed the first command.

Comment: Parsing output of `ls` is error prone as filenames may contain any character including space and newline.

Comment: there is a little problem, `ls -t | head -1` will list the current dir. this command won't work fine if I run ur command in another dir

Comment: @anubhava thx for ur advice, got it.I can make sure there is no special character in my case :3

Comment: @sammy since you are listing only `7z` files,  do 7z e `ls -t *.7z | head -1`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the below code for writing more than 1 command together in a single line.

`ls -t | head -1 && 7z e <file_name>.tar.7z` command for the extracting .7z file

Answer (score 0):

Here is a safer method of extracting last modified file in a directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -printf "%T@\0%p\0\0" |
    awk -F '\0' -v RS='\0\0' '$1 > maxt{maxt=$1; maxf=$2} END{printf "%s%s", maxf, FS}' |
    xargs -0 7z e
```

This required gnu find and gnu awk.

`-printf` option is using single NUL character or `\0'` as field separator and 2 NUL characters `\0\0` as record separator for `awk`.